# Why is this return hash giving me issues?

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a variable for a Javascript object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-javascript-object-key)

I can't figure out how I am messing this up.

My code gives me the error:

```
invalid property id
```

Code:

```
 return  { this.Obj.itemid :
               {  Color : this.Obj.color,
                  Name : this.Obj.name,
                  Year : this.Obj.year
                }
           };
```

I need to return these hashes as an array (thus the return), but no matter what I do, it either returns the error above, or the var reference is stringified. I can't actually get the dynamic js value in there as a key.

I've tried this:

```
" + this.Obj.itemid + "
```

and this:

```
var itemid = this.Obj.itemid;
return { itemid : {
         //etc..
    }}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this and this.Obj etc.. are all great because the right hand assignments are proper. I get all the correct values except the the var: this.Obj.itemid is ALWAYS stringified when on the left hand side - or used as a key. I will review your link; = thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use `this.Obj.itemid` in that way.

Instead, try something like:

```
var ret={};
ret[this.Obj.itemid]=
   {
      Color : this.Obj.color,
      Name : this.Obj.name,
      Year : this.Obj.year
   };
return ret;
```

Comment: wow. this worked wonderfully. Thanks a bunch. Real help.

Comment: I did - weird. I was just thinking - why isn't that checkmark green. Hmm. curious. I for sure checked it. Anyways, checked it again :-)

Answer (score 4):

What appears on the left-hand side of the colon in a property initializer must be a valid identifier, string literal, or numeric literal. It's always used literally. `this.Obj.itemid` is none of these things.

If you're trying to use the *value* of `this.Obj.itemid` as the property name, then:

```
var ret = {};
ret[this.Obj.itemid] = {
    Color : this.Obj.color,
    Name : this.Obj.name,
    Year : this.Obj.year
};
```

That takes advantage of the fact that you can use bracketed notation with any expression for the property name. `ret[this.Obj.itemid] = ...` will create a property on `ret` whose name is the result of the expression `this.Obj.itemid`.

Simpler example:

```
var foo = {};
var b = "bar";
foo[b] = 42;
console.log(foo.bar); // "42"
```